# How to set up a blacklist for insmod?

Tags: linux, kernel-modules, modprobe

I want to block a certain driver module from loading in the linux kernel.
So I created a file in /etc/modprobe.d/cdc_acm.conf. In this file I added the following line:

```
install cdc_acm /bin/false
```

This works as expected when issuing:

```
modprobe cdc-acm

libkmod: ERROR libkmod/libkmod-module.c:924
command_do: Error running install command for cdc_acm ERROR: could not
insert 'cdc_acm': Operation not permitted
```

The problem is that when I use the insmod utility the module is loaded:

```
insmod cdc-acm.ko

[ 1051.914578] cdc_acm 2-1.1:1.0:
usb_probe_interface [ 1051.919437] cdc_acm 2-1.1:1.0:
usb_probe_interface - got id [ 1051.926323] cdc_acm 2-1.1:1.0:
ttyACM0: USB ACM device [ 1051.934700] usbcore: registered new
interface driver cdc_acm [ 1051.941315] cdc_acm: USB Abstract Control
Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters
```

Why is this happening is there a way to create a blacklist file for insmod ?

Comment: Does `rm cdc-acm.ko` do what you want? `insmod` is *supposed* to work at a lower level than modprobe and pretty much just assume that you know what you are doing. You will get the same result from `insmod - < cdc-acm.ko` without insmod having any idea that you are loading cdc-acm.ko.

Comment: I need to have the driver on the filesystem, but to disable accidental loading of the driver, so I can't remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The blacklist is read by `modprobe` where insmod just tries to insert a module without bothering with dependencies or blacklists or anything.

`insmod` man page:

```
insmod is a trivial program to insert a module into the kernel. Most users will want to 
use modprobe(8) instead, which is more clever and can handle module dependencies.
```